# Weird Login Error(Password is correct, how-ever it will act as if it's not!)

Tags: php, authentication

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('db') or die("cannot select DB");
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $encryptedpass = hash('whirlpool', $pass);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE user='".$user."' AND pass='".$encryptedpass."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    echo("$encryptedpass");
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername=$row['user'];
            $dbpassword=$row['pass'];
        }
        if($user == $dbusername && $encryptedpass == $dbpassword)
        {
            echo("logged in");
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;
            header("Location: settings.php");
        } else 
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
    }
}
?>
```

The hashing echo works as it should, how-ever even though the user & pass are correct it says invald password.... Help would be great!

EDIT: Thats weird... When I enter the wrong pass, invalid password echo doesnt show up... How odd

Comment: Indent your code, and you'll immediately see why you don't get the Invalid message with the wrong name/password.  Invalid values means the SELECT will return 0 rows, so the 'else' clause should be attached to that 'if'.   Also, why are you checking name/passwords match in (numerous!=0) code when you p've already got the condition in the SQL.   Finally, you're open to SQL injection with the username.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the error is there, but the following (basically the same) works fine.
Make sure that your post values are actually being passed, and adding or die(mysql_error()) will tell you if you have any errors in your sql.

Also, you should escape your strings (if not using prepared statements)

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
/* Do connection */

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$encrypted = hash('whirlpool', $pass);

$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM players WHERE user = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$encrypted."'",$server)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0) {
    /* Login approved */
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    print $row['id'];

}else{  
    /* Could not login */
}
}
```